# How does Identity know if a password reset token has been used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have successfully implemented ASP.NET into an MVC Website and am curious to know how OWIN/Identity knows if an identiy token has already been used.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) on Microsoft says:

> Once a forgotten password token has been used, it's invalidated.

but how is this performed if the token isn't stored anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on the same page as you linked:

> The SecurityStamp field and associated code provides an extra layer of security to your app, when you change your password, you will be logged out of the browser you logged in with. The `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` method enables the app to validate the security token when the user logs in, which is used when you change a password or use the external login. This is needed to ensure that any tokens (cookies) generated with the old password are invalidated. In the sample project, if you change the users password then a new token is generated for the user, any previous tokens are invalidated and the SecurityStamp field is updated.

Comment: In other words: the password reset token contains / is based on the old SecurityStamp, and when the password reset succeeds, the user's SecurityStamp is updated, thereby invalidating the used token.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.Identity use its own database under the hood where all information about account, credentials, roles or token validation are stored. Structure should looks like:

[image]

Try to use tool **Connect to Database...** to interact with it.

Comment: That's nice, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: This only contains SecurityStamp? No Password reset token.